# Чем отличается findNavController() от createNavigateOnClickListener?

Tags: android, android-fragment, kotlin, fragment-manager, navigationcontroller

Есть два способа объявить переход от одного фрагмента в другой. Оба они используют Action - ту самую связь в графическом редакторе навигационного файла а-ля X-Code.
Все это с зависимостями в app Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.1.0"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$version_navigation"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$version_navigation"
}
```

Первый способ:

```
binder_obj.playButton.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment)
```

Второй способ:

```
binder_obj.tryAgainButton.setOnClickListener {view: View? ->
    view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_gameOverFragment2_to_gameFragment)
```

Зачем нам еще одна абстракция в виде view: View - вот это вопрос? В каких случаях это уместно и чем отличается `findNavController()` от `createNavigateOnClickListener`?

Answer (score 0):

Это одно и тоже. Первый вариант завёрнут в обёртку, которая возвращает `OnClickListener`.
Второй вариант - extension функция для `View`. Оба они в итоге вызывают метод [`public static NavController findNavController(@NonNull View view)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/Navigation.html#findNavController(android.view.View)),
который описан так:

> Find a NavController given a local View.
>        This method will locate the NavController associated with this view.
>        This is automatically populated for views that are managed by a NavHost and is intended for use by various  android.view.View.OnClickListener listener
>       interfaces.

Во фрагменте можно вызывать без view
`findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_gameOverFragment2_to_gameFragment)`